# PowerShell and XML data

Tags: xml, powershell

I currently have a requirement to use Powershell to retrieve data from an XML file. The data will be used to construct a users DN in AD. All I need the PS script to do is retrieve each users accountname and then create a string value with their OU structure.

XML Example

```
<user>
<accountname>SmithJ</accountname>
....
....
....
<OrgUnit>
<Org>
<OrgDescription>Admin Clerks</OrgDescription>
</Org>
<Org>
<OrgDescription>Administration Services(UK)</OrgDescription>
</Org>
<Org>
<OrgDescription>Global Admin</OrgDescription>
</Org>
<Org>
<OrgDescription>Contoso</OrgDescription>
</user>
```

The OU structure is bottom up in each of the user entries so this user SmithJ resides in the 'Admin Clerks' OU.

Example of what I need powershell to produce:

### AccountName

SmithJ

### Target OU

,OU=Admin Clerks,OU=Administration Services(UK),OU=Global Admin,OU=Contoso

Ideally this would be exported to CSV with an AccountName column and a 'TargetOU' column and the user data populated below.

I am new to powershell and I am currently learning it in my own time.

Could someone tell me if im approaching this correctly, so far I have

```
[xml]$userfile = Get-Content C:\Users.xml

foreach( $user in $userfile.user) 

{
Write-Output $AN.accountname
}

foreach( $user in $userfile.user.OrgUnit.Org)

{

$TargetOU = ",OU=" + $User.OrgDescription | Write-Host -NoNewline  

}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards

John

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to build the target OU string I would do this:

```
'OU=' + (($userfile.user.OrgUnit.ChildNodes | Select -expand OrgDescription) -join ',OU=')
```